# IO monad issues when trying to implement WAI HTTP Server + Fallback Proxy

Tags: haskell, proxy, haskell-wai

What I'm trying to do is to create a somewhat smart reverse proxy server that should process some requests on its own and forward the others to the backend of choice. To make it challenging I'm trying hard to do it in Haskell, which I am a total newbie in.

Here's the code I've come up so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.ByteString
import Network.HTTP.ReverseProxy
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger
import qualified Network.HTTP.Client as HC

helloApp :: Application
helloApp req respond =
  respond $ responseLBS status200 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] "Hello"

proxyStubApp :: Application
proxyStubApp req respond =
  respond $ responseLBS status200 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] "You've hit the stub"

proxyApp :: IO Application
proxyApp = do
  manager <- HC.newManager HC.defaultManagerSettings
  return $ waiProxyTo (const $ return $ WPRProxyDest ProxyDest { pdHost = "localhost", pdPort = 9393 }) defaultOnExc manager

app :: Application
app req respond =
  serve req respond
    where serve = lookupServeFunction req

lookupServeFunction :: Request -> Application
lookupServeFunction req
  | isInfixOf "sample_path" (rawPathInfo req) = proxyStubApp
  | otherwise                                 = helloApp

main = run 3011 =<< (logStdoutDev <$> return app)
```

It works fine, but when I exchange `proxyStubApp` for actual `proxyApp` I am forced to add `IO` all over the place. Particularly it gets added to `app`, consequently leaving me with the following compilation error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Request -> t5 -> t4’
            with actual type ‘IO Application’
The equation(s) for ‘app’ have two arguments,
but its type ‘IO Application’ has none
```

I feel like I understand why it is happening, but I'm out of ideas of how to cope with it :( Or am I doing something totally wrong?

Thank you!

P.S. Here are the dependencies should you want to compile the thing on your own: `wai warp http-types text bytestring wai-extra time http-reverse-proxy http-client`

Answer (score 1):

The `IO` in `IO Application` is kind-of redundant. Note that

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

so, expanding `proxyApp`'s arguments (what you already do in `proxyStubApp`), you get

```
proxyApp :: Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
proxyApp req continuation = do
     manager <- HC.newManager HC.defaultManagerSettings
     waiProxyTo (...) req respond
```

That works, because in either case

```
proxyApp :: IO Application
proxyApp = do
   manager <- HC.newManager ...
   ...
```

and

```
proxyApp :: Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
proxyApp req continuation = do
   manager <- HC.newManager ...
   ...
```

the IO action `HC.newManager ...` is "run within `IO`".

You may find it conceptually clearer to construct an `Application` in `IO` and hand it to some other place, and I won't argue with you. I want to note though, that you choose the `Application` based on the `Request`, so in a way you are in the hypothetical HTTP monad when choosing, so `lookupServeFunction`'s signature `Request -> Application` makes more sense to me.

If you want to keep that type signature for `proxyApp`, 
`lookupServeFunction` and `app` will have to be in `IO` as well and `main` will have to change accordingly, e.g.

```
myApp <- app
...
```

As haoformayor said, It is generally easier to work without the outer `IO` layer.

---

You might also like to simplify `main`.

```
fmap logStdoutDev (return app)
```

is the same as

```
return (logStdoutDev app)
```

and
    run 3011 =<< return (logStdoutDev app)

is the same as

```
run 3011 (logStdoutDev app)
```

You might want to install hlint, which will help you spot these.

Comment: I can see how `IO Application` can make sense. Imagine, it's an `Application` that is being returned as a result of an IO action, which looks quite like my case: `waiProxyTo` here is a sort of an app generator that depends on a `manager` which in turn is a result of an IO somehow. Can't it be that way?

Comment: I think the real point is that `a -> IO b` is isomorphic to `IO (a -> IO b)`. Any value of one of those types can be converted to the other. If you have `wibble :: a -> IO b` and `wobble :: IO (a -> IO b)`, `return wibble` gets you going forward and `(wobble >>=) . flip id` gets you going backward. (And of the two, `a -> IO b` is generally easier to work with, in e.g. situations like this one, although that's a subjective preference. The fewer monadic blankets you have to climb out of to peek your head out the better, I say.)

Comment: @haoformayor, does this mean that `proxyApp :: IO Application` should really be the same thing as `proxyApp :: Application`? Removing `IO` makes compiler upset at the line where I call `HC.newManager` and bind it with the following message `Couldn't match type ‘IO b0’ with ‘Request                         -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived’. Expected type: IO HC.Manager -> (HC.Manager -> IO b0) -> Application. Actual type: IO HC.Manager -> (HC.Manager -> IO b0) -> IO b0`... I wonder how long does it take to start making sense of these :-)

Comment: Maybe my answer is unclear. I'll try to clarify it in a moment.